# Script to take CSV run external file on a column then return output to file

Tags: batch-file, csv, windows-scripting

I'm looking for a bit of help with a windows script or DOS batch file.

I'm sure it's quite simple but I'm not sure where to start.

What I'm, looking to do is take a csv file that has two columns, "Username","Password".

It will then take the password column, run it through a program called encrypt_pwd.exe then output the result of the file which is just a string to a new file called encryptedPassword.csv that is has "username","encrypted password".

An example of the file will simply be:

```
Phil,test
John,test2
Andy,test
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: can you show a few lines of your csv file including the column names?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off
echo "Username","Password" > encryptedPassword.csv
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=,; skip=1" %%i in (%1) do (
        for /f %%x in ('encrypt_pwd.exe %%j') do (echo %%i,%%x) >> encryptedPassword.csv
)
```

Comment: +1 , but you can use "skip=1" in outer FOR options instead of IF condition.

Comment: modified it to this:@echo off
set _Inputfile=c:\Heritage\test.csv
echo "Username","Password" > encryptedPassword.csv
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=,; skip=1" %%i in (%_Inputfile%) do (
        for /f %%x in ('encrypt_pwd.exe %%j') do (echo %%i,%%x) >> encryptedPassword.csv
) and works perfecty